# Wortart von "deinen" in Genitivkonstruktion

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case, pronoun, genitive

In einem Satz wie diesem:

> Die Haare meiner Schwester sind länger als die der deinen.

- Was für eine Wortart ist *deinen* und in welchen Fall steht es?

Der Hintergrund der Frage ist, dass das Wort immer *deinen* ist, egal auf welches Geschlecht, welchen Numerus und welchen Kasus es sich bezieht.

> Ich sehe die Haare deiner/deines Schwestern/Bruders länger an als die der/des deinen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ein stellvertretend gebrauchtes Possessivpronomen nach einem bestimmtem Artikel, welches schwach dekliniert wird. In den Beispielen steht es im Genitiv.

Nach einem bestimmten Artikel sind diese Formen gleichwertig mit jenen, die zusätzlich noch ein `-ig-` enthalten → *der deinigen*.

Zum leichteren Verständnis, um welchen Fall es sich handelt, kann man *dein-* mit *blau-* ersetzen (der Satz verliert dann zwar seinen Sinn, aber es hilft):

> Die Haare meiner Schwester sind länger als die der blauen.

Stellvertretend gebrauchte Possessivpronomen werden nach einem bestimmten Artikel also wie Adjektive dekliniert. Fachsprachlich wird diese Verwendung *anaphorisch* genannt.

Siehe auch:

[Link](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Poss3.html)
[Link](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Deklinationstyp/Schwach.html)
http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphorik

Außerdem (siehe Link No. 1):

> Die Possessivpronomen können  [aber auch] ohne Artikel stellvertretend für ein Nomen stehen. Die endungslose Form Maskulin Singular erhält dann die Endung *-er*, die endungslosen Formen des Neutrum Singular die Endung *-es*.
>
> *Mein**er*** ist schneller als *dein**er***.
> *Ihr**es*** ist schneller als *eur**es***.
> Wir leihen euch *unsere*.

Comment: Was ist ein "stellvetretend gebrauchtes" Pronomen? Alle Pronomen sind stellvertretend. Ausserdem, seit wann gibt es bei Pronomen starke und schwache Deklination? Ausserdem, ist nicht der Hinweis auf "-ig" eher ein Indiz für ein Adjektiv?

Comment: @Emanuel Nein sind sie nicht. Deine Schwester spielt Geige (begleitend). Meine spielt Cello (stellvertretend im grammatikalischen Sinn/"anaphorisch").